# How can I get the media inside a post?

Tags: posts, rest-api, media, api

I’m new to WordPress, so please forgive me if my question is not clear or vague. I did a lot of research, but I didn’t figure out how to do the trick. I’m developing a Xamarin application for Android devices. This application retrieves posts from a WordPress site and replicates the news it finds inside of itself. I learned about the  [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/)
 to get the news. The problem is that the WordPress site maintainer uses different media inside of the news: audios, videos, galleries, and so on. The pages are explicitly in `video`, `audio`, and `gallery` format. Using the above-mentioned API, I get the news with the text inside them, but I don’t get the URLs' resources relative to the media. An example, one of the news has the format equal to `video`:

[image]

The API doesn’t return anything that let me retrieve the URL of the video to replicate it inside the UI of my application. The same happens with the `audio` and `gallery` formats. How can I retrieve the media URLs that are inside the news?

Comment: Where is the URL of the video stored in WordPress?

Comment: I don’t know. The only thing I know is that one news has the video format (a video appears inside of it when I open its Web page).

Comment: Ok, but the question I asked is what you have to find out. Probably the theme does some magic behind the scenes, retrieving the value from postmeta. But this is only a guess

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry. I have to retrieve the video URL.